# autocomplete input field also accepting user entered value

Tags: php, forms, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete in my form. But the problem which I am facing is that autocomplete input  field also accepting user input. How to disallow this and force user to only select value from autocompelte search. here is my code :

```
<form>
   <td><input type="text"  name="firstname" id = "aaa"></td>  (this is autocomplete field)  
   <td><input type="text"  name=""lastname" id = "bbb"></td>    
<input type = submit value = "submit">
</form>
```

This is autocomplete links file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="frontend-script.js"></script>
```

This is Script.Js file

```
 $( function() {
  $( "#tutorial_name" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'backend-script.php'  
    });
});
```

and this is backend file

```
<?php
include('database.php'); 

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vcent WHERE concent LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $tutorialData = array(); 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $data['id']    = $row['id']; 
   $data['value'] = $row['concent'];
   array_push($tutorialData, $data);
} 
}
 echo json_encode($tutorialData);
?>
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a built-in way to allow only autocomplete suggestions. You could consider intercepting the `submit` event on the form that displays an error if the value does not match a suggestion. You would also need to consider adding some matching server-side logic too in case a user submits the form with JavaScript disabled. Alternatively, you may wish to look into using a `<select>` element or radios to present the user with a predefined list to choose from instead.